# Limiting Scope of UnitTest using Rhino stubs

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

I'm working on a unit test for a service method, that has dependencies. Simplified:

```
public class ConditionChecker
{
    private SqlConnection _connection;

    public bool CanDoSomething()
    {
        return _connection.State == ConnectionState.Open;
    }
}

public class A
{
    public ConditionChecker Checker { get; set; }

    public bool CanInvokeA()
    {
        return Checker.CanDoSomething();
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class ATests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestCanInvokeA()
    {
        // arrange
        A a = new A();
        ConditionChecker checker = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ConditionChecker>();
        checker.Stub(x => x.CanDoSomething()).Return(true);
        a.Checker = checker;

        // act
        bool actual = a.CanInvokeA();

        // assert
        Assert.AreEqual(true, actual);
    }
}
```

What I want is to completely bypass the implementation of `ConditionChecker.CanDoSomething`, which is why I stub the call, still I run into a null reference Exception during my test, since the `_connection` member is not set. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just mark your method as `virtual`, it will work:

```
public virtual bool CanDoSomething()
{
}
```

Since behind the scene Rhino Mock will create a dynamic proxy for `ConditionChecker`, so you need to mark `virtual` to allow Rhino Mock to override it.

Comment: Thanks, so this restriction comes from Castle.DynamicProxy, right?

Comment: Ah! And what if the constructor of ´ConditionChecker´ contains code that I want to bypass? That would be impossible, wouldn't it?

Comment: @SebastianEdelmeier: you need to *inject the dependencies* into `ConditionChecker` constructor rather than creating them inside constructor  if you want to passby

Comment: Great, that's what I wanted to hear =). Changed it this way and it works!